# Copy PCB project on Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I want to make a new modified version of a PCB project on Altium while keeping the original project. How can I create a new project and copy everything from the first one?

Comment: I don't know Altium, but my first guess would be to simply copy all project files and paste into a new location, then rename the new project.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd do it is to use the 'Project Packager', found in the *Project* menu on the top bar. This will wrap all of your project files into a zip file and place it at some location you specify.

This method also (optionally) fixes the paths of each item to be relative to the zip file root, meaning you won't need to re-link all the items to the project like you would if you just copied and pasted them from the filesystem.

If your modified project only requires changing part values or part placement (i.e., marking some components as 'Do Not Populate' (DNP), changing resistor/capacitor values, etc.) then I would tend to recommend using the 'Variants' feature, which allows you to make these changes in a single project and have varied documentation/fabrication outputs. If you need different routing or major changes, however, then the project packager feature is likely your best option.